# Is there a way to schedule the sending of messages on whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, automation, android-11

Is there a way **to schedule** the sending of messages on whatsapp using some particular program or script (obviously having the root of the device)?

I tried many applications to schedule sending messages, but none of them was automatic, they all needed user interaction.

I also tried to create some sort of scripts but with no results because they were in conflict with the operation of the application. My phone has Android 11 and I noticed that going on with the versions is getting more and more complex to work at the programming and automation level.

In particular, I would need something **automatic** that requires **no interaction to send these messages**

Comment: Does the solution need to be mobile-only?  I ask because you're more likely to be able to write some sort of batch script that can be scheduled to run an ADB command; however, I think that would be more appropriate to post up in SU for rather than here.

Comment: Yes the solution does not have to be mobile-only

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment so I had to write this as an answer? There is a TaskerNet task to send WhatsApp messages here: [WhatsApp Message](https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8m5meDrLUT9uhCsO9WUCdS1Ylmtq8lBwug2ylx2wIbryo7683GNx01h8IcH1niuZ%2BY%3D&id=Task%3AWhatsapp%20Message#). I have not personally used it, so I don't know if it works. Also, if your phone is rooted there are a couple of guides using autovoice and tasker, and one using SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already tried these methods and they do not meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution for a long long time, the best what I found is to use Takser task. It's described in this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/bnnkvg/send_whatsapp_with_sql_with_locked_screen/f2xi0zx/?context=3

However, with latest Whatsapp versions it doesn't work with sending to groups, couldn't find out why.

Alternatively, you can use custom Whatsapp client, as I do now